# Is there a way to prevent setting the same property more than once when deserializing a object?

Tags: c#, .net, yamldotnet

Deserializing the following yaml fragment using YamlDotNet:

> ```
>        bill-to:  &id001
>             street: |-
>                     123 Tornado Alley
>                     Suite 16
>             city:   East Westville
>             city:   West Westville
>             state:  KS
> ```

Will call the `city` property setter twice, once for each value..

Is there a way in YamlDotNet to prevent this sort of behavior and make YamlDotNext explode when the same setter is called the second time?

I'm using YamlDotNet in this case, and YAML in general, as a configuration format for my application, and it is very counter-intuitive for users to be able to assign to configuration keys different values...